# ".AspNetCore.Correlation." state property not found. Azure B2C

Tags: azure-web-app-service, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

```
".AspNetCore.Correlation." state property not found
```

We have been getting a number of these errors in our Web App whilst hitting the standard `/signin-oidc` callback url.
I am using .net core 2.1 and using the `.AddAzureAdB2C(...` from the Azure samples.

Nothing crazy in our setup, afaik.
We are leveraging 3 of the the `OpenIdConnectEvents`

1. `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` to add a Guid to the state parameter -since the iOS12 change to drop the auth cookie to SameSite.None and also to pass a GA tracking id through when it is present from the referring site.
2. `OnRemoteFailure` to redirect to appropriate error pages.
3. `OnTokenValidated` to validate the Guid added in 1. and strip the GA id out again.

Our setup is a load balanced (traffic manager) azure environment, with 2 app services (north/west) - both sharing the same application `ClientId` and `ClientSecret`, `RedirectUri` etc.
The DataProtection key(s) for the App Services are shared and held in Azure Blob storage.

Can't really see what the problems is, done a fair bit of searching around but getting nowhere. If anyone can shed any light, it would be much appreciated.